# Get all names of property of another class - Unity 5 C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created this class called Genes and I want to get all it's properties inside of another script. I tried using

```
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Genes).GetProperties();
```

but props is an empty array. I think typeof isn't working. This is my class Genes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Genes 
{
    private float size;
    private float speed;
    private float probability;
    private int color;

    public Genes(float size, float speed, float probability, int color) 
    {
        this.size = size; 
        this.speed = speed; 
        this.probability = probability; 
        this.color = color; 
    }
}
```

and I basically want to run over size, speed, probability and color using a foreach loop. What is the problem?

Comment: Properties need to be public in order to be returned by the method .GetProperties(). As described on the documentation: [System.Type.GetProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetProperties)

Comment: you have **fields**, no **properties**. You should use `GetFields` instead, or make those fields properties (something like `public float Size { get; set; }`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either make your fields properties which have getters and setters:

```
public class Genes 
{
    private float Size { get; set; }
    private float Speed { get; set; }
    private float Probability { get; set; }
    private int Color { get; set; }

    public Genes(float size, float speed, float probability, int color) 
    {
        this.Size = size; 
        this.Speed = speed; 
        this.Probability = probability; 
        this.Color = color; 
    }
}
```

or use `GetFields` if you really want fields:

```
typeof(Genes).GetFields();
```

No matter what you chose, these members should furthermore either be `public`, or you have to use the [`BindingFlags.NonPublic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags) to look for non-public members:

```
typeof(Genes).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

or

```
typeof(Genes).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Comment: I thought using public properties was generally a bad idea? Would you say using BindingFlags.NonPublic is the better option?

Comment: Who sais public properties are bad? Neither of them is good or bad in itself, you have to think about if you need public access or not.

Comment: Read that exposing the structure of a class to another class by using public is bad code and you should rather use getters and setters...

Comment: @IceRevenge Actually having a **public field** is _generally_ a bad idea. Also Auto-Implemented Properties consist of a private field and getter and setter. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).